# Error Forbidden WampServer

Tags: wampserver

I instaled wamp 64bit in my windows 8 ;
after install my icon was orange color 
but , i click form service apache > install service \ 
and **Apache is ok running** (Changed Color to **Green**)

But 
After open `localhost/` in my browser , Show me This error :

```
Forbidden 

You don't have permission to access / on this server. enter code here
```

---

but from **127.0.0.1 is running very good** `(from localhost not working)`

my windows is `microsoft windows 8`

Comment: The answers given for this question might work but is not the actual reason why its not accessible. 

By default the wampserver is put to offline mode. If you click on the "*green w icon*" in systray, you could find the option to put it online. Doing so would make localhost accessible again. Cheers.

Comment: You're right, "going online" makes localhost/ work, but localhost/phpmyadmin/ is still forbidden.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i remove this line from httpd.conf apache
**Deny from all**

before my change :

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

after my changes :

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**My problem was solved this way**

good time :D

Answer (score 12):

Found this question on Google.

For Windows 8, along with Erfan Safarpoor response; be sure to “Allow from 127.0.0.1″ to “Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1″ as well as change "Listen 80" to "Listen 0.0.0.0:80" - This will resolve the issue of getting Forbidden on localhost and phpmyadmin. :3